# Why is $(this).data('id') not working when using in a dialog?

Tags: jquery, cordova, onsen-ui, phonegap

I originally had this function to remove an item when the `delete-item` button is clicked:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".delete-item", function() {

                    console.log("Removing "+$(this).data('id'));
                    var id=$(this).data('id');
                    var parent=$(this).parent().parent().parent();      
                    parent.remove();
                    $(".subitem-row"+id).remove();
                    applyCartChanges();

});
```

It works fine. But when I try to do a dialog (using OnsenUI and PhoneGap) to confirm it first before removing, like this:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".delete-item", function() {

        ons.notification.confirm({
          message: getTrans('Remove from cart?','remove_from_cart') ,     
          title: dialog_title_default ,
          buttonLabels: [ getTrans('Yes','yes') ,  getTrans('No','no') ],
          animation: 'default', // or 'none'
          primaryButtonIndex: 1,
          cancelable: true,
          callback: function(index) {

               if (index==0){                         

                    console.log("Removing "+$(this).data('id'));
                    var id=$(this).data('id');
                    var parent=$(this).parent().parent().parent();      
                    parent.remove();
                    $(".subitem-row"+id).remove();
                    applyCartChanges();

               }
          }
        });

});
```

Then it suddenly doesn't work anymore :( In the console, it says `undefined` for the `$(this).data('id')`. Any ideas why?

Comment: Show us your HTML code. hard for us to point out the error without

Comment: try with `$(this).attr('data-id')`

Comment: You are missing the reference to `this` inside callback function. Check the answer

Comment: try using arrow function instead of callback: function(index){
try:
callback: index => {
this will resolve your closure issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the reference to `this` is not obtained as a clicked element inside the dialog. So, rewrite your code as

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".delete-item", function() {
        var _this = this;
        ons.notification.confirm({
          message: getTrans('Remove from cart?','remove_from_cart') ,     
          title: dialog_title_default ,
          buttonLabels: [ getTrans('Yes','yes') ,  getTrans('No','no') ],
          animation: 'default', // or 'none'
          primaryButtonIndex: 1,
          cancelable: true,
          callback: function(index) {

               if (index==0){                         

                    console.log("Removing "+$(_this).data('id'));
                    var id=$(_this).data('id');
                    var parent=$(_this).parent().parent().parent();      
                    parent.remove();
                    $(".subitem-row"+id).remove();
                    applyCartChanges();

               }
          }
        });

});
```

Notice that i have taken the reference of `this` inside a new variable `_this` so it will be accessible inside the dialog.

Comment: Ah! I learned something new, thank you :) Will accept your answer once it allows me in a few mins!